# Singular or plural: "The figure(s) in the center and on the right show that..."

Tags: grammar

In a paper I'm writing, there are three figures: one on the left, one in the center and one on the right. I want to say something about the one in the center and the one on the right. Should I use the singular or the plural form of the word *figure* in this sentence?

> The figure(s) in the center and on the right show that...

I had assumed I should use the plural form. A native speaker said I should use the singular. If both usages sound awkward, I would also appreciate suggestions for alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use singular only if you repeat *the figure*, as follows:

> The figure in the center and the figure on the right show that ...

To indicate how the aforementioned parses:

> [The figure in the center] and [the figure on the right] show that ...

You can use plural by not repeating *the figure*:

> The figures in the center and on the right show that ...

Which parses to:

> The figures [in the center and on the right] show that ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to two different figures at once (both the right and the center), you should refer to them as *figures*. If you say

> The figure in the center and on the right

it sounds like you are referring to a single object that is both in the center and on the right. To maintain the verb agreement with the plural subject, make sure to use *show*.

Comment: The singular form had just sounded wrong to me, but this sounds right, it _could_ have a meaning like this. I am indeed referrring to two different figures, so I'll use the plural. Thanks!